# Simplification of $\exp(k\log(\mathbf{A}))$ with $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{A} \in SE(3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, lie-groups, matrix-exponential

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a real matrix that belongs to $SE(3)$ i.e. has the following form:
$$ 
\mathbf{A} = \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{R} & \mathbf{t}\\
\mathbf{0}_{1\times 3} & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
With $\mathbf{R} \in SO(3)$ ($\mathbf{R}$ represents a rotation matrix), and $\mathbf{t} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ ($\mathbf{t}$ represents a translation vector).

Given this I am wondering if there is a way to simplify the following expression:
$$\exp\left( k \log\left( \mathbf{A}  \right) \right)$$
Where $\{k \in \mathbb{R}\,|\, 0\leq k \leq 1\}$, $\exp(\cdot)$ is the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) and $\log(\cdot)$ is the [matrix logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix).

Such that $k$ does not appear at the middle of the expression, so that it can be expressed as:
$$ f(k) \exp(\log(\mathbf{A})) = f(k) \mathbf{A} \quad\text{ or}\quad \exp(\log(f(k)\mathbf{A})) = f(k) \mathbf{A}$$

I've found closed form solutions for $\exp(\cdot)$ and $\log(\cdot)$ [here](https://ingmec.ual.es/%7Ejlblanco/papers/jlblanco2010geometry3D_techrep.pdf#page=49) (at p.47). For example, for the exponential map:

$$\exp(\mathbf{X}) = \begin{pmatrix} 
\exp(\mathbf{w}^\wedge) & \mathbf{V}\mathbf{v}\\
\mathbf{0}_{1\times3} & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
Where $\mathbf{w}\in \mathbb{R}^3, \mathbf{v}\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and:
$$\begin{align}
\exp(\mathbf{w}^\wedge) &= \mathbf{I}_{3\times3} + \frac{\sin{\theta}}{\theta}\mathbf{w}^\wedge + \frac{1-\cos\theta}{\theta^2}(\mathbf{w}^\wedge)^2\\
\mathbf{V} &= \mathbf{I}_{3\times3} + \frac{1-\cos\theta}{\theta^2}\mathbf{w}^\wedge + \frac{\theta - \sin\theta}{\theta^3}(\mathbf{w}^\wedge)^2\\
\theta &= \lVert \mathbf{w} \lVert
\end{align}$$

But knowing that there is not a closed-form solution for $\cos(k\theta)$ as noted in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1435167/cosine-and-sine-of-the-angle-multiplied-by-a-scalar), this makes me think that this simplification is not feasible.